# .htaccess rewrite rule /directory/ to php files?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to turn:

```
/1/2
```

into:

```
/negocio/2.php?shopURL=1
```

I don't know much of htaccess and my rule isn't working. This is what I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.+)? /negocio$2.php/?shopURL=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.+?)/?$ negocio$2.php?shopURL=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^1/2/(.*) http://www.example.com/negocio/2.php?shopURL=1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Sorry. I think the question was confusing I just clarified it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^(negocio)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ negocio/$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Sorry. I think the question was confusing I just clarified it.